# Accessing items in a list, and forming graphs

Tags: python, graph, image-segmentation

I have a list of 2D numpy arrays:

```
linelist = [[[0,0],[1,0]],[[0,0],[0,1]],[[1,0],[1,1]],[[0,1],[1,1]],[[1,2],[3,1]],[[1,2],[2,2]],[[3,1],[3,2]],[[2,2],[3,2]]]
```

Each line in linelist is the array of vertices connecting the edge.
These elements are the lines that form two squares:

```
-----
|   |
-----

    -----
    |   |
    -----
```

I want to form two graphs, one for each square. To do this, I use a for loop. If neither vertex is present in the graph, then we form a new graph. If one vertex is present in the linelist, then it gets added to a present graph. In order for two lines to be connected, they need to share a vertex in common. However, I am having trouble coding this. 
This is what I have so far:

```
    graphs = [[]]
    i=0
    for elements in linelist:
        for graph in graphs:
            if elements[0] not in graph[i] and elements[1] not in graph[i]:
                graphs.append([])
                graphs[i].append(elements)
                i=i+1
            else:
                graphs[i].append(elements)
```

Comment: Bit vague description here. Does linelist contain n graphs of each 2x2 adjacency matrix? Is the goal to construct 1 graph or n graphs ?

Comment: The goal is to construct n graphs. "If neither vertex is present in the graph, then we form a new graph." Graphs should contain multiple graphs. It is not an adjacency matrix. It is just a list of the edges of the graph, given by the vertices.

Comment: An edge list usually is formatted as v1, v2 where v1 -> v2. The edge list you posted will produce many separate graphs and not "clustered" squares as you would want. You can make 1 giant graph including the directed edges and then look for disjoint subgraphs, is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest doing a 'diffusion-like' process over the graph to find the disjoint subgraphs. One algorithm that comes to mind is [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search); it works by looking for what nodes can be reached from a start node.

```
linelist = [[[0,0],[1,0]],[[0,0],[0,1]],[[1,0],[1,1]],[[0,1],[1,1]],[[1,2],[3,1]],[[1,2],[2,2]],[[3,1],[3,2]],[[2,2],[3,2]]] 

# edge list usually reads v1 -> v2
graph = {}
# however these are lines so symmetry is assumed
for l in linelist:
    v1, v2 = map(tuple, l)
    graph[v1] = graph.get(v1, ()) + (v2,)      
    graph[v2] = graph.get(v2, ()) + (v1,)

def BFS(graph):
    """
    Implement breadth-first search
    """
    # get nodes
    nodes = list(graph.keys())
    graphs = []
    # check all nodes 
    while nodes:
        # initialize BFS
        toCheck = [nodes[0]]
        discovered = []
        # run bfs
        while toCheck:
            startNode = toCheck.pop()
            for neighbor in graph.get(startNode):
                if neighbor not in discovered:
                    discovered.append(neighbor)
                    toCheck.append(neighbor)
                    nodes.remove(neighbor)
        # add discovered graphs
        graphs.append(discovered)
    return graphs
print(BFS(graph))
for idx, graph in enumerate(BFS(graph)):
    print(f"This is {idx} graph with nodes {graph}")
```

## Output

```
This is 0 graph with nodes [(1, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0), (1, 1)]
This is 1 graph with nodes [(3, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2), (3, 2)]
```

You may be interested in the package `networkx` for analyzing graphs. For instance finding the disjoint subgraphs is pretty trivial:

```
import networkx as nx
tmp = [tuple(tuple(j) for j in i) for i in linelist]
graph = nx.Graph(tmp);
for idx, graph in enumerate(nx.connected_components(graph)):
    print(idx, graph)
```

Comment: This works. I may look into the networkx package. My goal is to label each graph, and then develop an algorithm that can classify each graph.

Comment: I wonder if your algorithm could also output the lines associated with each subgraph. I need to draw the graphs using those lines. I suppose I could create lines using the vertices, just connecting one to the next.

Comment: It can. `networkx` provides `matplotlib` draw functions (easiest). Since the ordering is preserved in terms of connectedness drawing the lines can be inferred from the sequence.  But I leave that up to you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

My approach involves 2 passes over the list. In the first pass, I will look at the vertices and assign a graph number to each (1, 2, ...) If both vertices have not been seen, I will assign a new graph number. Otherwise, assign it to an existing one.

In the second pass, I go through the list and  group the edges that belong to the same graph number together. Here is the code:

```py
import collections
import itertools
import pprint


linelist = [[[0,0],[1,0]],[[0,0],[0,1]],[[1,0],[1,1]],[[0,1],[1,1]],[[1,2],[3,1]],[[1,2],[2,2]],[[3,1],[3,2]],[[2,2],[3,2]]]


# First pass: Look at the vertices and figure out which graph they
# belong to
vertices = {}
graph_numbers = itertools.count(1)
for v1, v2 in linelist:
    v1 = tuple(v1)
    v2 = tuple(v2)
    graph_number = vertices.get(v1) or vertices.get(v2) or next(graph_numbers)
    vertices[v1] = graph_number
    vertices[v2] = graph_number

print('Vertices:')
pprint.pprint(vertices)


# Second pass: Sort edges
graphs = collections.defaultdict(list)
for v1, v2 in linelist:
    graph_number = vertices[tuple(v1)]
    graphs[graph_number].append([v1, v2])

print('Graphs:')
pprint.pprint(graphs)
```

Output:

```
Vertices:
{(0, 0): 1,
 (0, 1): 1,
 (1, 0): 1,
 (1, 1): 1,
 (1, 2): 2,
 (2, 2): 2,
 (3, 1): 2,
 (3, 2): 2}
Graphs:
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [[[0, 0], [1, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 1]], [[1, 0], [1, 1]], [[0, 1], [1, 1]]], 2: [[[1, 2], [3, 1]], [[1, 2], [2, 2]], [[3, 1], [3, 2]], [[2, 2], [3, 2]]]})
```

Notes

- I have to convert each vertex from a list to a tuple because list cannot be a dictionary's key.
- `graphs` behaves like a dictionary, the keys are graph numbers (1, 2, ...) and the values are list of edges

A little explanation of the line

```
graph_number = vertices.get(v1) or vertices.get(v2) or next(graph_numbers)
```

That line is roughly equal to:

```
number1 = vertices.get(v1)
number2 = vertices.get(v2)
if number1 is None and number2 is None:
    graph_number = next(graph_numbers)
elif number1 is not None:
    graph_number = number1
else:
    graph_number = number2
```

Which says: If both v1 and v2 are not in the vertices, generate a new number (i.e. `next(graph_numbers)`). Otherwise, assign `graph_number` to whichever value that is not `None`.

Not only that line is succinct, it takes advantage of Python's short circuit feature: The interpreter first evaluate `vertices.get(v1)`. If this returns a number (1, 2, ...) then the interpreter will return that number and  skips evaluating the `vertices.get(v2) or next(graph_numbers)` part.

If `vertices.get(v1)` returns `None`, which is `False` in Python, then the interpreter will evaluate the next segment of the `or`: `vertices.get(v2)`. Again, if this returns a non-zero number, then the evaluation stops and that number is return. If `vertices.get(v2)` returns `None`,  then the interpreter evaluates the last segment, `next(graph_numbers)` and returns that value.

Comment: What is going on in the line: graph_number = vertices.get(v1) or vertices.get(v2) or next(graph_numbers) ? Also, how do you learn these things? Books or experience?